# How do I install jest?

Tags: npm, jestjs

Been trying to install **jest** with this command:

`npm i --global jest`

and get these messages:

```
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
/Users/GRW/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/jest -> /Users/GRW/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js
npm WARN jsdom@16.4.0 requires a peer of canvas@^2.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ws@7.3.1 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ws@7.3.1 requires a peer of utf-8-validate@^5.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ jest@26.4.2
updated 1 package in 32.731s
```

Have tried manually installing peer dependencies with:

```
npm i --save --global canvas@^2.5.0
npm i --save --global bufferutil@^4.0.1
npm i --save --global utf-8-validate@^5.0.2
```

but still am unable to install **jest**.

How do I install **jest**?

**EDIT**: Forget about the global install and the peer dependency warnings go away, but I still get:
**-bash: jest: command not found**

Comment: don't use `npm i --global jest` use `npm i --global jest-cli`

Comment: Get the same result with that command.

Comment: Check your node and npm versions required for jest and make sure you meet those requirements.

Comment: Can't find any version requirements, but I have node 10.13.0 and npm 6.4.1

Comment: You're able to install it. What you see is a log of successfully installed NPM package. Installing peer deps doesn't make sense, they will only clutter the system. This should be done only if you receive error messages that some package wasn't found. The problem is very specific to NVM which can only be seen in logs and which you didn't mention. The executable is available at /Users/GRW/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/jest . See https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#environment-variables . Bash should be made aware of NVM_BIN

Comment: After installation, I figured [jest -v] would show it had installed correctly by showing the version, but I only ever got [-bash: jest: command not found]. Did find a solution that (after multiple additional tweaks) did finally seem to run my tests: [npm run test].

Comment: Did have an nvm issue that appeared to be blocking me upgrading my node/npm versions beyond 10/6. Deactivated nvm and was able to upgrade node/npm to 14.8.0/6.14.7, but even upgraded that didn't solve my jest issues.

Comment: Decided to completely uninstall everything (jest, node, npm, nvm) and start from scratch. Reinstalled node/npm, and was able to install jest and get the [jest -v] command to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I seemed to have a prior installation of **nvm** that kept installations of different versions of **node** in different directories, I decided to start fresh.

Uninstalled and deleted **jest**, **node**, **npm**, and **nvm**.

Reinstalled **node**/**npm**, and was able to install **jest** and get the `jest -v` command to work properly.